# React Native generate signed APK issue (EBUSY: resource busy or locked)

Tags: android, node.js, windows, npm, react-native

I am pretty new to react native and recently attempting to build a simple app (Android) for my learning. I am experiencing trouble when I am trying to compile a signed apk based on the steps from the official React Native website.

When I run the command "gradlew assembleRelease" on my command prompt (I am using Windows 7), I get the following error:

--START LOG--

```
...removed for clarity

[02/12/2017, 23:21:15] <START> Initializing Packager
                                                 [02/12/2017, 23:21:19] <STA
RT> Building Haste Map
                                                                           [
02/12/2017, 23:21:19] <END>   Building Haste Map (601ms)
                                                                           [
02/12/2017, 23:21:19] <END>   Initializing Packager (4522ms)
                                                                           [
02/12/2017, 23:21:19] <START> Transforming files
Warning: The transform cache was reset.
                                                                           C
:\15\node_modules\write-file-atomic\index.js:98
throw err
^

Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\USR~1.LIE\AppData\Local\Temp\react-native-packager-cache-4b500ae1\e0\b5092aindex.android.js.210794830
7' -> 'C:\Users\USR~1.LIE\AppData\Local\Temp\react-native-packager-cache-4b50
0ae1\e0\b5092aindex.android.js'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:809:18)
at writeFileSync (C:\15\node_modules\write-file-atomic\index.js:95:8)
at Object.writeSync (C:/15/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager
/src/lib/TransformCache.js:130:3)
at _getTransformedCode (C:/15/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packa
ger/src/node-haste/Module.js:299:22)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 28.308 secs
```

--END LOG--

Btw, I am currently running the following versions:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.40.0
node: 6.9.1
npm: 4.0.5

What went wrong and how could I resolve this issue (or is there any workarounds)?
Appreciate great help from the crowd!